# Replace nulls with using random max/min values

Tags: python

I would like to replace the nulls in the column "Lower Confidence Interval" for a random number (it has to be or the min and or the max of the same column). I have tried this but it doesn't work. What I am missing?

```
minimo = np.nanmin(df_copy['Lower Confidence Interval']) 
maximo = np.nanmax(df_copy['Lower Confidence Interval'])
    
import random
    
for value in df['Lower Confidence Interval']:
    if value == 0:
        value.fill_na(np.random.choice([minimo, maximo])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest a map with a lambda function

```
minimo = np.nanmin(df_copy['Lower Confidence Interval']) 
maximo = np.nanmax(df_copy['Lower Confidence Interval'])

df_copy['Lower Confidence Interval'] = df_copy['Lower Confidence Interval'].map(
    lambda x: np.random.choice([minimo, maximo]) if np.isnan(x) else x
)
```

If you are not familiar with this it basicaly translates to this pseudocode:

```
for each element x of df_copy['Lower Confidence Interval']
   x = lambda(x)

function lambda(x)
   if np.isnan(x)
      return np.random.choice([minimo, maximo])
   else
      return x
```

Comment: Thank you. When you say: ** else return x ** You are returning to lambda(x). What is the meaning of lambda? Is lambda the repetition of each element?

Comment: lamda is an anonymous function, I would suggest taking a look at https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_lambda.asp 
The function 'map' allows you to apply a lambda function to each element of a Series (df['col'] is a pd.Series object)

Answer (score 0):

The error is that while you iterate over each of the value they are `float` and not dataframe object hence the `fill_na` will not work on it. I have used the same ideas as your question and created a pandas lambda function:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df_dict = {"Lower Confidence Interval":[1,2,2.5,6,5.5,np.nan, np.nan]}
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(df_dict)
```

Output:

```
df
   Lower Confidence Interval
0                        1.0
1                        2.0
2                        2.5
3                        6.0
4                        5.5
5                        NaN
6                        NaN
```

Rest code follows:

```
minimo = np.nanmin(df['Lower Confidence Interval'])
maximo = np.nanmax(df['Lower Confidence Interval'])


# Assuming you have done this. (Note: it makes it as float)
df.fillna(0, inplace=True)

def replace_na(x):
    if x == float(0):
        return np.random.choice([minimo, maximo])
    else:
        return x
df["Lower Confidence Interval"] = df["Lower Confidence Interval"].apply(replace_na)
```

After replacing the the min and max for a column the output is:

```
df
Out[15]: 
   Lower Confidence Interval
0                        1.0
1                        2.0
2                        2.5
3                        6.0
4                        5.5
5                        1.0
6                        6.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Import modules:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import random
```

Create example data

```
df_copy = pd.DataFrame({'Lower Confidence Interval':[0,1,np.nan,8]})
minimo = np.nanmin(df_copy['Lower Confidence Interval']) 
maximo = np.nanmax(df_copy['Lower Confidence Interval'])
```

Count number of NANs

```
cnt=df_copy['Lower Confidence Interval'].isnull().sum()
```

Replace NANs randomly with min,max values:

```
df_copy[df_copy['Lower Confidence Interval'].isnull()] = np.random.choice([minimo, maximo],cnt).reshape(cnt,1)
```

Comment: could you please explain me why are you using .**.reshape** at the end?

Comment: If for example 3 values are replaced, it will turn the numpy array in shape (3,1). Without this step the array remains (3,) and the last step will not work.